# Flag dialogue loading animation appears on each click

Tags: bug, status-declined, flags

When clicking on flag multiple times, it shows a new animation for each time we clicked on the flagging link.

This mostly happens with a slow internet connection when we click multiple time to open it when it was already loading.

Know it wasn't a big issue and don't know whether it was reported earlier, but I can't find it on my search. So just reporting it.

[image: Lots of loading crawlers]

Comment: I managed to get 2 here. I simply can't click fast enough to get more! You must have fastest fingers on Meta ;)

Comment: you can accomplish it with some practice :)

Comment: Fix? Don't do that.